# Getting null value from table

Tags: java, sql, jsp, collections

i have a piece of jsp code . this code takes data from a table and displays it on a console
For `integer` values it is working good but for `String` values it displays `null`
the issue is not with the `table` . i have tried other tables also but same result

jsp code :

```
<%
int mots_id = 0 ; 
String mots_name = "" ;
String accesstype = "" ;
GetAccess obj = new GetAccess();
List<GetAccessVO> accesslist = obj.access(attUID);
if(accesslist!=null)
{
    Iterator<GetAccessVO> iter = accesslist.iterator();    

        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            GetAccessVO getaccessVO = iter.next();
            mots_id = getaccessVO.getmotsid();
            String  mots_name = getaccessVO.getmotsname();   
            String  accesstype = getaccessVO.getaccess();  
            out.println(accesstype);  // it displays null 
        }  
} 
%>
```

java code :

```
public class GetAccess{
    final static DBConnection db=new DBConnection(); 
    public List<GetAccessVO> access(String attuid)
    {
        List<GetAccessVO> accesslist = new ArrayList<GetAccessVO>();
        try
        {
            Connection con = db.getConnection();
            String query ="select mots_id ,mots_name,access_type from ENV_TEAM where userid = ?";   
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, attuid);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) 
            { 
                GetAccessVO getaccessVO = new GetAccessVO();
                getaccessVO.setmotsid(rs.getInt(1));
                getaccessVO.setmotsname(rs.getString(2));
                getaccessVO.setaccess(rs.getString(3));
                accesslist.add(getaccessVO);
            }
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();
            con.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return accesslist; 
    }
}
```

the setter getter class :

```
public class GetAccessVO {

    private int mots_id;
    private String mots_name;
    private String access;

    public String getmotsname() {
        return mots_name;
    }

    public void setmotsname(String mots_name) {
        this.mots_name = mots_name;
    }

    public int getmotsid() {
        return mots_id;
    }

    public void setmotsid(int mots_id) {
        this.mots_id = mots_id;
    }

    public String getaccess() {
        return access;
    }

    public void setaccess(String access) {
        this.access = access;
    }
}
```

i have tried almost everything but the `String` values always are null

```
SQL> select * from env_team ;

USERID     MOTS_ID MOTS_NAME                      ACCESS_TYPE
------- ---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
as045e        7921 BDS                            external
```

Comment: Try to use JSP only for presentation purpose, follow MVC pattern.

Comment: Are you sure your query returns value?

Comment: yes it returns ... i have edited the post for this

Comment: How try with `GetAccessVO` implements `Serializable`?

Comment: @suninsky actually i didnt get your point

Comment: I means to try with `GetAccessVO implements Serializable`.

Comment: Before setting it to the object trying printing it then you can know whether it returned the exact resultset on not

Comment: Check the input String, whether it has any leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: @suninsky same result